# Why is cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor() independent of device?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

Different devices may have different shared memory sizes, register counts.

Why is [cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1g5a5d67a3c907371559ba692195e8a38c) independent of device?

It doesn't need a device as a parameter.

Comment: It is not, it uses the currently active device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the active device set by [cudaSetDevice()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g159587909ffa0791bbe4b40187a4c6bb).